# How to scan a file with antivirus on upload in Java?

Tags: java, file-upload

I am working on an application which requires file upload and it also requires
to scan the file with available antivirus on server.

I have heard abt APIS available from Symantec for application server.

Situatuion is like, I need to deploy the application at different places
in the future. So, I am thinking to place a configuration file
from where I am going to fetch available Antivirus & its path.

I want to use any available antivirus on server and then
using command line, I want to pass file name and result back.

I am confused in passing file and retrieving back results.

Is it possible?

Comment: Generally your question is: "is it possible to run command line with parameters and get the output back using java?" Am I right?

Comment: You could also use the VirusTotal.com API...

Comment: Maybe All Capital Words Can Attract A Little Bit Of Extra Attention, But This Attention Will Combine With Negative Attitude As Well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
String[] commands =  new String[5];
                  commands[0] = "cmd";
                  commands[1] = "/c";
                  commands[2] = "C:\\Program Files\\AVG\\AVG10\\avgscanx.exe";
                  commands[3] = "/scan=" + filename;
                  commands[4] = "/report=" + virusoutput;


                 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                 Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
```

Commnad line would be better option for you. then read the log file to solve the problem.

Comment: I have used similar kind of approach..

Comment: how about in llinux?

Comment: @HardikMishra can you share your solution as I also searching for the same

Comment: @PatelRomil: We had not found perfect solution. It was around this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I just googled up and found an interesting article have a look at [here](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3711331/Implementing-an-Anti-Virus-File-Scan-in-JEE-Applications.htm)

> To implement a virus file scan in Java, a third-party package needs to be used. For the purposes of this article, I will use Symantec Scan Engine (SSE) package, which comes with Java APIs. This package is an application that serves as a TCP/IP server and has a programming interface and enables Java applications to incorporate support for content scanning technologies. For this article, I used Symantec Scan Engine 5.1, which is available as a Unix or Windows install.

quick reference:

```
public void scanFile(byte[] fileBytes, String fileName)
   throws IOException, Exception {

   if (scan) {
      AVClient avc = new AVClient(avServer, avPort, avMode);
      if (avc.scanfile(fileName, fileBytes) == -1) {
         throw new VirusException("WARNING: A virus was detected in
            your attachment: " + fileName + "<br>Please scan
            your system with the latest antivirus software with
            updated virus definitions and try again.");
      }
   }
}
```

then

```
catch (Exception ex) {
   logger.error(ex);
   if (ex instanceof VirusException) {
      // do something here
   }
   else {
      // there was some other error – handle it
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi JJ.. thanks for it but i do not want to use 'Symantec' API as per mentioned scanrio in my post :)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi the link you've provided no longer works, could you post the full code please? Also tell me where you got your clamAV java client from, thank you

Comment: @Maurice This is ~9 year old answer and may be no longer valid. Let me update it later today.

Answer (score 4):

Use VirusTotal Public API V2.0 implementation in Java and Go written by 
[VIGHNESWAR RAO](https://vighnesh.org)
available at https://code.vighnesh.org/virustotal 
it has rich features to scan files, URLs, domains, IP addresses and to get a detailed report about scan.
 with this API your files will be scanned with 56 antivirus engines. and all antivirus engines are run in virustotal cloud so especially you no need to maintain or run any antivirus engines.
an important feature of this API is it has methods to accept java.io.FileInputStream or java.io.File as arguments.
All API features are clearly explained with examples.
to use this api
step-1: create an account in http://virustotal.com (VirusTotal, a subsidiary of Google) and get API key
step-2: visit https://code.vighnesh.org/virustotal and download required jar files
step-3: just use the methods provided by API.
you can use examples provided at 
 
Java : https://code.vighnesh.org/virustotal/Java/examples.html 
 
Go   : https://code.vighnesh.org/virustotal/Go/examples.html

Comment: virustotal is a google company. visit http://virustotal.com to get detailed information without knowing all these how can you say it is spam.