# Scan pdf Files saved in Oracle DB Server

Tags: java, oracle

The scenario is My web application needs to upload or download the files to and from the  Web application using GWT.

Can you please tell me if we have any **Java API to do virus scanning** while uploading or downloading the files from and to the database?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: scanning for viruses?

Comment: yes exactly   we need to scan for viruses

Comment: Save the file to disk and use [`java.lang.Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to run a virus scanner through the command line.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721406/how-to-scan-a-file-with-antivirus-on-upload-in-java) helps